# Dynamic jquery slider

Tags: jquery, dom, slider

I have a growing list of objects that I want to attach a slider to. I'm dynamically building a ul/li that holds the objects and when attaching a slider to the function the sliders are built for each li item but they all control the last LI. has anyone encountered/solved this?

Code snippet:

```
    $('<span>').attr({
        class: 'sliderO'
    }).appendTo('#' + lyrVar.liID);

    $('.sliderO').slider({
        min: 0, max: 1, value: 1, step: 0.10,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            lyrVar.setOpacity(ui.value);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: For each element that's create, I added an extra field to assign a unique ID to each element.

```
$('<span>').attr({
    class: 'sliderO',
    id: lyrVar.sliderID
}).appendTo('#' + lyrVar.liID);
```